# How to downsample a not-power-of-2 texture in UnrealEngine?

Tags: c++, image, unreal-engine4

I am rendering the Viewport with a resolution of something like 1920x1080 multiplied by a Oversampling value like 4. Now i need to downsample from the rendered Resolution 7680‬x4320 back to the 1920x1080.

Are there any functions in Unreal I could use for that ? Or any Library (windows only) which handle this nicely ?
Or what would be a propper way of writing this my own ?

We tried to implement a downsampling but it only works if SnapshotScale is 2, when its higher than 2 it doesn't seem to have an effect regarding image quality.

```
UTexture2D* AAVESnapShotManager::DownsampleTexture(UTexture2D* Texture)
{

    UTexture2D* Result = UTexture2D::CreateTransient(RenderSettings.imageWidth, RenderSettings.imageHeight, PF_B8G8R8A8);

    void* TextureDataVoid = Texture->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Lock(LOCK_READ_ONLY);

    void* ResultDataVoid = Result->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Lock(LOCK_READ_WRITE);

    FColor* TextureData = (FColor*)TextureDataVoid;
    FColor* ResultData = (FColor*)ResultDataVoid;

    int32 WindowSize = RenderSettings.resolutionScale / 2;

    for (int x = 0; x < Result->GetSizeX(); ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Result->GetSizeY(); ++y)
        {
            const uint32 ResultIndex = y * Result->GetSizeX() + x;

            uint32_t R = 0, G = 0, B = 0, A = 0;

            int32 Samples = 0;

            for (int32 dx = -WindowSize; dx < WindowSize; ++dx)
            {
                for (int32 dy = -WindowSize; dy < WindowSize; ++dy)
                {

                    int32 PosX = (x * RenderSettings.resolutionScale + dx);
                    int32 PosY = (y * RenderSettings.resolutionScale + dy);

                    if (PosX < 0 || PosX >= Texture->GetSizeX() || PosY < 0 || PosY >= Texture->GetSizeY())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    size_t TextureIndex = PosY * Texture->GetSizeX() + PosX;
                    FColor& Color = TextureData[TextureIndex];
                    R += Color.R;
                    G += Color.G;
                    B += Color.B;
                    A += Color.A;
                    ++Samples;
                }
            }

            ResultData[ResultIndex] = FColor(R / Samples, G / Samples, B / Samples, A / Samples);
        }
    }

    Texture->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Unlock();
    Result->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Unlock();

    Result->UpdateResource();

    return Result;

}
```

I expect a high quality oversampled Texture output, working with any positive int value in SnapshotScale.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. It's not really direct, but it involves no writing of image filtering or importing of libraries.

1. Make an unlit Material with nodes TextureObject->TextureSample-> connect to Emissive.
2. Use the texture you start with in your function to populate the Texture Object on a Material Instance Dynamic of the material.
3. Use the "Draw Material to Render Target" function to draw the Material Instance Dynamic to a Render Target that is pre-set with your target resolution.

Comment: Thanks but "Draw Material to Render Target" doesn't give good downsampling results, even if I go from 2048 to 512.